# ERROR: Unable to find 'libcurl/7.50.3@lasote/stable' in remotes VS 2015

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015, vc++2015, appveyor

Собираю либу curlpp. Беру пример сборки с [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jpbarrette/curlpp/build/job/sk1b9evxt7s5rqg0), но не могу понять как добавить либу curl в проект.
После комманды:

```
conan install --build=missing -s compiler="Visual Studio" -s compiler.version=%PRJ_GEN_VERSION% -s build_type=%PRJ_CFG% .
```

Вот что выводит:

```
    conan install --build=missing -s compiler="Visual Studio" -s compiler.version=%PRJ_GEN_VERSION% -s build_type=%PRJ_CFG% .
    Configuration:
    [settings]
    arch=x86_64
    arch_build=x86_64
    build_type=Release
    compiler=Visual Studio
    compiler.runtime=MD
    compiler.version=14
    os=Windows
    os_build=Windows
    [options]
    [build_requires]
    [env]
    
    libcurl/7.50.3@lasote/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
    libcurl/7.50.3@lasote/stable: Trying with 'conan-center'...
    ERROR: Unable to find 'libcurl/7.50.3@lasote/stable' in remotes
```

Если кто собирал подскажите куда нужно класть сорцы и либы для сборки??
Собираю на VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого будет возникать такая ошибка используйте все комманды из [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jpbarrette/curlpp/build/job/sk1b9evxt7s5rqg0) и прописуйте все переменные и пути к исполняемым файлам!

> Что бы найти переменные среды заходи в "панель управления"->"система и
>   безопасность"->"система"->"Дополнительный параметры системы" и нажмите
>   кнопку "Переменные среды".

Моя проблема была устранена повторным скачиванием исходников коммандой git.
Всем удачи!